# Chirping noise -2014 Ford Escape

Tags: ford, noise, escape, intermittent-problems

2014 Ford Escape-Approximately 25000 miles. I am hearing a chirping noise  like cricket at times while driving. I don’t hear it while idling. It seems to be coming from right front of car. This area of car was hit by another vehicle around 1.5 months ago and was repaired at body shop around a month ago. I haven’t noticed until last couple of weeks. It isn’t getting worse yet. Is there any chance it is body shop related or is it definitely mechanical?

Update: I drove it today. I didn’t hear noise at all. I’ll continue monitoring it. I’ll update if any changes

Comment: Have you checked the brakes to ensure the squealer hasn't started contacting the rotor? Check your pads to make sure they aren't worn out.

Comment: I haven’t had chance to yet, but I will soon.

Comment: Does it happen on light throttle, or only under moderate to heavy throttle like getting on the highway, or passing, etc?  I'm wondering if it's the wastegate.

Comment: Later this week, I’ll be driving vehicle again and I’ll listen more closely to see exactly when it happens(type of throttle). I drove it yesterday, but I didn’t hear it at all.

Comment: Is the noise independent of the type of surface the car I driving on, or do you find that bumpy surfaces produce it? My ford currently also has an annoying chirp, caused by some metal to metal contact on a clip supporting the hand brake cable. It’s far worse on bumps as the cable is vibrating up and down with the suspension

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how and where the other vehicle impacted your car. If the wheel was hit, then it could very well be the right-front wheel bearing. Usually when a bearing gets damaged it takes a while for it to show.
To check the wheel bearing put the car on the parking brake, the transmission in neutral and jack up the right front wheel. It should spin easily without any strange noises. Also grab the wheel with both hands and check for any excessive play.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the noise is unrelated to the crash.  Check your pulleys and accessory belt tension—sometimes those can chirp.

Answer (score -1):

I had a chirping noise in my Escape and I couldn't figure out where it was coming from. Found out it was my sunglasses in the sunglasses holder above the rear view mirror. Hahah!